# Class registration using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, factory-pattern

I'm learning about Factory Pattern and I am using [THIS](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) article as a source. In it, there is this piece of code:

```
class ProductFactory {
  private HashMap m_RegisteredProducts = new HashMap();

  public void registerProduct (String productID, Class productClass) {
    m_RegisteredProducts.put(productID, productClass);
  }

  public Product createProduct(String productID) {
    Class productClass = (Class)m_RegisteredProducts.get(productID);
    Constructor productConstructor = cClass.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[] { String.class });
    return (Product)productConstructor.newInstance(new Object[] { });
  }
}
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how `createProduct()` method works. When I'm trying to use this code I get `` Non-static method `getDeclaredConstructor(java.lang.Class<?>...)' cannot be referenced from a static context `` error. `productClass` variable is declared but never used so there is clearly something wrong with the code but I can't figure what exactly. I checked similar questions on SO but don't know how to repurpose them for this case. Reflection is a really confusing subject for me.

My questions:

1. What is wrong with this code?
2. Why it is passing `new Class[] { String.class }` in `getDeclaredConstrutor()` method and what does it mean?
3. Why is it passing Object array in `newInstance()` instead of just single object?

Comment: Unrelated note: the article you've been reading might be very old (or poorly written). Using raw collections (that includes maps in the broader sense) is strongly discouraged since generics and Java 5.

Comment: Also: the `cannot be referenced from a static context` error has nothing to do with reflection. You're likely invoking the method from the class context, i.e. `ProductFactory.createProduct(...)` instead of invoking it from an instance of `ProductFactory`. Plenty of dupes out there...

Comment: @Mena Isn't the static reference error based on that OP attempts to invoke `Class.getDeclaredConstructor(...)` when he rather should use `productClass.getDeclaredConstructor(...)` since it's an instance method of the class `Class` and not static? Or am I just blind an can't find the declaration + initialization of `cClass`?

Comment: @Mena Actually I get this error without using ``createProduct()`` method. I basically copied the code above and get this error. My IDE (IntelliJ) underlines this red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Question 1*

There are several things wrong about this code.

1. It just does not compile because `cClass` member is missing. Logically, It should be `productClass.getDeclaredConstructor` instead.
2. Raw `HashMap` is used instead of generically typed `Map<String, Class<? extends Product>>`. Also raw typing for `Class` and `Constructor`.
3. The naming `m_RegisteredProducts` does not respect Java naming conventions.

*Question 2*

`new Class[] { String.class }` arg aims to retrieve the constructor with a single `String` arg, for example `public Product(String id)`.

It could have been retrieved with just

```
productClass.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
```

because it is not mandatory to create arrays for varargs.

*Question 3*

This array arg just looks like a blunder. The constructor instance is retrieved for one with `String` arg, but it is passing something else to instantiate it. So inevitably there will be an exception thrown.

*Conclusion*

There are too many wrong or inaccurate things in this example and probably in the article itself. I'd recommend choosing another one.